# Transiting Albania to Italy

Tags: transit, automobiles, road-trips, ferries, albania

I plan to do a trip in the late summer with my wife by car, going from Romania to Italy, but we'd like to get the ferry from Durres or maybe another city in Albania, and I would like to know some things

1. It is safe to transit the Albania for now?
2. The roads are in a good condition?
3. Also I would like to get some advices where to find a fine and cheap ferry to Brindisi or Bari from Albania? we don't need confort, just want to be safe and in time

And of course if you have some more advices for me about this, I would be glad to hear them from you.

Thanks

Comment: "Safe" and "good condition" are somewhat subjective, and finding a ferry service is a "travel agent" question, which is off topic here.  Can you rephrase your question so it can be answered more objectively?

Comment: Oh God, mate I have asked for an advice, not for what you know it is right or not in this world, If I would like to go to an agent I'll do that for sure. BTW, you can learn from @vartur on how to answer some simple questions if you know the right answer. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: And the nicest moment in all this chat is that you acted like a little child and down voted my question, instead of saying something smart. Pfff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes Albania is a safe country
2. The roads are generally not in excellent condition, but if you stick to the main roads that should be more than OK
3. I generally use http://www.directferries.com/ to find ferry trips, but there are other similar websites that you can find using your favourite search engine